# How do I align different types of numbers, decimals and currencies in the same column in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

How do I align different types of numbers, decimals and currencies in the same column in crystal reports? All the numbers are right-align and at the same position. I have tried to place them in text objects boxes and still not working.  It changes depending on how long the number or currency is. 
For example:

```
--------- 55,7171
$120,288,250.49
```

Or:

```
-------------------------- 1
$1,792,693,086.36
```

I need it to show like this:

```
-----------55,7171
$120,288,250.49
```

Or:

```
---------------------- 1
$1,792,693,086.36
```

Comment: maybe I am missing something but it is super unclear to me what you need.

Comment: How do all those dashes signify that being a number? I feel like I'm missing something and/or this is totally unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a formula field and write below code:

```
    '<div align="right">'+CSTR(Number field)+' </div> <p> </p>'+' <div 
align="left">'+CSTR(currency field)+ '</div>'
```

Go to format field and check option `Can Grow` along with this go to `Paragraph` tab and change the `Text Interpretation` to `HTML Text`